# Adding scss files to rails-assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bower, rails-assets

I'm creating a bower file, which I'm then adding at https://rails-assets.org/.

I can pull the file in fine, however I can't reference the `scss` file. The `css` file gets imported fine, however becomes useless because it merely contains variables.

Importing like so to application.scss in rails:

```
@import 'dist/stylesheets/helpers/_variables.scss';
@import 'dist/stylesheets/helpers/variables.css';
```

bower.json

```
{
    "name": "torpedo",
    "main": [
      "dist/stylesheets/helpers/_normalize.scss",
      "dist/stylesheets/helpers/variables.css"
    ],
    "ignore": [
        "source",
        "spec",
        ".bowerrc",
        ".gitignore",
        ".jshintignore",
        ".jshintrc",
        "bower.json",
        "gruntfile.js",
        "package.json",
        "README.md"
    ]
}
```